# Logout a user from all devices if user hit logout from one device in java

Tags: java

I'm Developing a java Application, In this my requirement is- a user can login from different devices but if he hits logout on one devices then user's id will logout from other devices automatically.I am doing this through servlets and session but unable to solve.

Thanks.

Comment: Maintaining a single session ? If I'm the developer, I'l maintain list of session for a specific user on container.

Comment: Is it possible to maintain single session on different devices.if yes then How?

Comment: No. That's weird and you can't. Look at second part in my comment.

Comment: So.. tell me how it will happen through different sessions?As i see when user login in application , then a new session is created for each user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have 3 devices:

```
1. Desktop
2. Mobile
3. iPad
```

Your application have a listener which keeps on looking at table in database.

When user logs-out from any one of the device you will set status in database as LOGOUT. Automatically other devices listener will come to know and execute logout code for respective device.

**Sample design:**

[image]

---

For real-time, push a JMS message upon logging off from any one device and keep other devices subscribed to the topic.

Comment: Google does provide 'logout from all devices' functionality! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a record of users with opened sessions (via flag in the DDBB, in user table, as example) and check that flag when user do whatever he do...

When a user log in any device to the application set that flag to true and if he closes the session in any device set that flag to false and return login error when he tries to do anything else in another opened session (wich will be in any other device)...

Its very simple solution and it adds only a new (simple) query per request so I think that is not so bad...